# Libpcap API does not remove the filter

Tags: libpcap

I am using lib-pcap library for installing/uninstalling the filters.

For installing the pcap filter, i use 
pcap_compile followed by pcap_setfilter which works fine.

and for uninstalling the filter, i use pcap_freecode but unfortunately, it does not seems to remove the above install filter.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`pcap_freecode()`, as the name suggests, doesn't un-install filters; if there were an API to un-install a filter, it would have a different name.  It's used to free the memory allocated by `pcap_compile()` (a *copy* of which is installed by `pcap_setfilter()`).

Unfortunately, there's no API to un-install a filter. However, you can install a filter that accepts all packets, which will have the same effect as un-installing a filter would.  Pass an empty string to `pcap_compile()` (empty string, i.e. `""`, not a null pointer), and it will compile that string to a filter that accepts all packets.

Comment: Thanks Guy for the reply. So essentially if we pass an empty string "", it will clear off all the perviously installed filters.

Comment: There's only one filter - if you have a filter installed with `pcap_setfilter()`, and you call `pcap_setfilter()` again, the old filter is removed and replaced with the new filter.  If the new filter was compiled from the filter string `""`, then it's a filter that doesn't filter out anything, so, in effect, it clears out the previous filter.